# Turn off scaling in Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side, galleria

When [Galleria](http://galleria.io) is in fullscreen mode, I want it to display images pixel-for-pixel, i.e. with no scaling at all.

My initial plan was to do this by both:

- using `fullscreenCrop: false`, because [the docs](http://galleria.io/docs/options/) say that, "**false** will scale down so the entire image fits", and
- ensuring (I already have a mechanism for doing this) that the ["big" image file](http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/)'s:

  - height (px) ≦ the screen's height (px) and
  - width (px) ≦ the screen's width (px).

Unfortunately:

- the docs neglect to note that "**false** will also scale *up* so the entire image fits" (i.e. if both *the image's height (px) < the screen's height (px)* **and** *the image's width (px) < the screen's width (px)*), and
- I do not have, nor do I want to have, a mechanism for ensuring that the "big" image file's

  - height (px) = the screen's height (px) or
  - width (px) = the screen's width (px).

Given all this, please can you suggest how I might achieve my objective?

Comment: @David, before you posted this comment, and indeed within a second of being able to do so, I had already accepted your answer below. I don't think I could really have accepted it at a faster rate!

Comment: Yea, that’s great but you should also accept some of your other questions as your general rate (61%) is pretty low. The higher rate you have, the more likely you will get quality answers.

Comment: @David, thanks for the tip. I realise you're trying to help me. Nevertheless, I tend to only accept answers that I'm confident are definitively correct, because I believe that to be more important than worrying about a comparatively arbitrary statistic. Thanks again, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent scaling by adding these two options:

```
maxScaleRatio: 1
minScaleRatio: 1
```

You probably only need the first one to prevent upscale. But the second one prevents downscale as well. Read more: http://galleria.io/docs/options/maxScaleRatio/